# Change status in manufacturer admin controller - prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, controller, prestashop

Hello i'm having trouble with the following:
In my store (prestashop1.6) in homepage i have a slider for all manufacturer (active == 1) but i don't want to show all, so i...

- add a new field in ps_manufacturer (like active field) and named homepage;
- changed the classes/manufacturer.php (line 178) to add the new field (homepage)

  '.($active ? 'WHERE m.`active` = 1 AND m.`homepage` = 1' : '' )
- in AdminManufacturersController.php (line 98) i've added

  'homepage' => array(
  'title' => $this->l('Enabled'),
  'homepage' => 'status',
  'type' => 'bool',
  'align' => 'center',
  'class' => 'fixed-width-xs',
  'orderby' => false
  )
  And all works well but in i don't know this?
  where do i change to in prestashop backoffice when i change the homepage field it submit for ps_manufacturer.homepage field????
  to have the same action like active...
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
 'homepage' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('homepage'),
            'active' => 'homepage',
            'type' => 'bool',
            'align' => 'center',
            'class' => 'fixed-width-xs',
            'orderby' => false
        )
```

And try to add the new field in the Manufacturer.php class, so you need to override Manufacturer.php class, so you need to create a class in override/classes/Manufacturer.php

```
<?php 
    Class Manufacturer extends ManufacturerCore
    {
        public $homepage;

        public function __construct($id = null, $id_lang = null)
        {
            self::$definition['fields']['homepage'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_BOOL);
            parent::__construct($id, $id_lang);
        }
    }
?>
```

Dont forget to delete cache/class_index.php

Comment: thanks @tarek fellah for the help, but doesn't work...i've tryed override (doesn't work, then i've made the changes in classes/Manufacturer.php to see if does work and again with no success).
But thanks anyway.

Comment: i think the problem is when i click on Homepage icon (cross or check) i  think that should have to trigger something to update ps_manufacturer.homepage for that id_manufacturer...

Comment: I made a mistake parent::__construct($id, $id_lang); i forget $ in id

Comment: Yes i saw, and i've try with $ but with no success :(

Comment: Try to enable the debug mode and paste error if you have one

Comment: Hello @tarek fellah 
This is the error
Warning on line 551 in file /home/ruisonik/public_html/testes/classes/controller/AdminController.php
[2] count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Warning on line 1829 in file /home/ruisonik/public_html/testes/classes/controller/AdminController.php
[2] Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ruisonik/public_html/testes/classes/Cookie.php:79)

Comment: if you share all code, we can investigate